# base href on IE issue

Tags: internet-explorer, href, radix

I use `<base href="/">` to make my site run correctly with mod_rewrite and it works perfect on all browsers except Internet Explorer. Is not loading css styles and javascripts. How can i deal with this

Comment: This is a known bug and can be fixed with javascript:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13373180/482115

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your issue, but the `base` tag is supposed to contain an absolute path, you are specifying a relative one.

An absolute path would be something like:

```
<base href="http://example.com/" />
```

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4

These other questions may help you:

- [Should we use <base href="" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362258/should-we-use-base-href)
- [Base href ignored in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758366/base-href-ignored-in-ie9)

Comment: And do you think i don't read this before asking the question? Is nothing wrong using base like i do. <base href="/"> or <base href="http://example.com/" /> gives me the same results on other browsers work in IE don't

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan said - using an absolute path for IE is necessary (dont know why but it behaves differently than other browsers.. surprise surprise..)

You might even find the following link helpful:
http://notes.minty.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Fixing_Base_Href_Javascript_Document.Location_For_Internet_Explorer